# Obtain in Java from a Map, a Set with unique elements

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have this `Map<String, Set<String>>`:

```
{upload=[ADMIN], configure.accounts=[ADMIN, CONSULT], consult=[ADMIN, CONSULT], configure.merchants=[MANAGER, ADMIN], configure.invoices=[MANAGER, ADMIN], graphics=[MANAGER, ADMIN]}
```

and I want to obtain a structure `Set<String>` like the next one:

```
[ADMIN, CONSULT, MANAGER]
```

Where the data is filtered obtaining all the possible values from the Set within the Map. I can do this if I iterate the entire Map and compares the values, adding those that are not currently in the `Set`.

Is there some function to do this?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to check whether the individual values are already in the `Set` -- the set will take care of that, that's what sets are for. Just iterate the values and add them to the set of all values.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("accounts", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "CONSULT")));
data.put("merchants", new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("MANAGER", "ADMIN")));

Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
for (Set<String> set : data.values()) {
    values.addAll(set);
}
```

If you are using Java 8, you can also replace the `for` loop with a `foreach` statement:

```
data.values().forEach(values::addAll);
```

Afterwards, `values` is `[MANAGER, ADMIN, CONSULT]`.

Comment: For java 8, replace the for-loop with  `data.values().forEach(values::addAll);`

Comment: @bradimus Thanks, added.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 solution:

```
 Map<String, Set<String>> test;
 Set<String> set = test.values()
                       .stream()
                       .flatMap(t->t.stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

No matter if you use Java 8 or Java lower than 8. Your end goal is to receive a `Set<String>` of elements because the elements in the Set<> are distinct.

Observing through the stream. First we are iterating over the values of the collection which are of type List. Then we use flatMap in order to transform this Set into a Stream of their elements.  The terminal operation is to actually collect them in a Set which will ensure that our elements are distinct.

Comment: You have to put all those generic classes in `code` format, or they are interpreted as HTML tags....

Answer (score 0):

From a Map you can retrieve all the Sets using `map.values()`. There you an Collection of Sets.

With this code you can get all unique sets

```
Map<String, Set<String>> accounts = yourData;
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();
foreach(Set<String> data: account.values()) {
   uniqueSet.addAll(data);
}
```